# What do the 'in' and 'out' keywords mean in D?

Tags: d

What do the `in` and `out` keywords in D actually mean and do? From looking around at functions using these for their parameters I understand that the `in` keyword is used for function input and the `out` keyword is used for parameters which are basically passed by reference.

Is that understanding correctly, and what do  they actually allow or disallow a programmer to do?

Comment: Just a related note. Those keywords are also used in the Design By Contract feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, you basically get it. `in` expands to `const scope` meaning you cannot change the variable (or anything it points to) and also are not supposed to keep a reference to it anywhere (`scope` is not actually implemented in most cases though). Basically, `in` is look, don't touch.

`out` means the given variable receives a value. It is very similar to `ref` - changes to it inside the function are also seen on the outside - with the small difference that out variables are initialized to their normal init value, clearing the value they had before the function was called.

Basically, `void foo(out int a) {}` == `void foo(ref int a) { a = 0; /* inserted automatically */ }`

Comment: So how does `void func(in int value)` differ from `void func(const int value)`?

Comment: It doesn't. Since `int` is a value type, the (supposed, again, not really implemented) restriction of `scope`, not allowing the reference to escape, doesn't apply.